# Why can't the instance member be accessed from the lambda of the enum constructor?

Tags: java, lambda, enums

In the code below, I am trying to output the value of a symbol that is an instance variable of Operation from a PLUS constant.

But I can't access that variable.

What's the problem?

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS("+", (x, y) -> {
        System.out.println(symbol);
        return x + y;
    }),
    MINUS("-", (x, y) -> x - y),
    TIMES("*", (x, y) -> x * y),
    DIVIDE("/", (x, y) -> x / y);

    Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    protected final String symbol;
    private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;

    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return op.applyAsDouble(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `symbol` is not in-scope. we can imagine the enum-values as a special kind of static fields of the enum.

Comment: The lambda that is passed to PLUS (constructor) doesn't have the context of an instance variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lambda expression is not a member of the `enum`, so it cannot access member variables from the `enum` directly. It also has no access to `protected` and `private` members of the enum. Also, at the point where the lambda is passed to the constructor, the member variables of the `enum` are not in scope.

A possible solution is to pass `symbol` as a third parameter to the lambda expression, but that means you'll have to use a different functional interface than `DoubleBinaryOperator`.

For example:

```
interface CalculationOperation {
    double calculate(double x, double y, String symbol);
}

public enum Operation {
    PLUS("+", (x, y, symbol) -> {
        System.out.println(symbol);
        return x + y;
    }),
    MINUS("-", (x, y, symbol) -> x - y),
    TIMES("*", (x, y, symbol) -> x * y),
    DIVIDE("/", (x, y, symbol) -> x / y);

    Operation(String symbol, CalculationOperation op) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    protected final String symbol;
    private final CalculationOperation op;

    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return op.calculate(x, y, symbol);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
import java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Supplier;


public class Test {

    public enum Operation {
        PLUS("+", (x, y) -> x + y, "verbose"),
        MINUS("-", (x, y) -> x - y),
        TIMES("*", (x, y) -> x * y),
        DIVIDE("/", (x, y) -> x / y);
        
        Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
            this(symbol, op, null);
        }

        Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op, String command) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.op = op;
            if("verbose".equalsIgnoreCase(command))
                operation = verboseWrapper;
            else
                operation = silentWrapper;
        }

        public String getSymbol() {
            
            return symbol;
        }

        protected String symbol;
        
        private DoubleBinaryOperator op;
        private Supplier<DoubleBinaryOperator> verboseWrapper = (() -> {System.out.println(symbol); return op; });
        private Supplier<DoubleBinaryOperator> silentWrapper = (() -> {return op; });

        private final Supplier<DoubleBinaryOperator> operation;
        
        public double apply(double x, double y) {
            
            return operation.get().applyAsDouble(x, y);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
                
        Operation plus = Operation.PLUS;
        
        plus.apply(1, 3);
        
        Operation minus = Operation.MINUS;
        
        minus.apply(1, 3);
    }

}
```